# rails options_from_collection_for_select - display proper data in dropdown from API and user selects from dropdown

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, api, view

Currently building my first rails app ... I'm using an external API to get the information. I can seed the db locally and see the results of that data in the dropdown menu that the user sees, but I would like this information to come from the API instead.

This code displays categories for what I have in my seed.db, but I need to pull from the api and display those categories, then I would like to show the items related to that specific category when a user selects that particular category. I plan on using JS for this but open to suggestions for ways to do that in Rails - since I am new! -

in the view - (displays dropdown of categories found in seed.db)

```
   <select>
      <option value="category">Select Book Category</option>
      <%= options_from_collection_for_select(Category.all, :id, :title) %>
   </select>
```

in the controller - I am parsing the information correctly from the api (I'm sure it's not the best format but it's working). I'm able to iterate through in the corresponding view and show the information from the parsed info in the view. It's just a matter of connecting the dots in the dropdown menu and displaying that information correctly now.

in the controller -

```
def index
  base_url = 'sample url from google api using'
  key = ENV['GOOGLE_API_KEY'] 
  url = base_url + key

  response = RestClient.get(url)
  @events = JSON.parse(response)

  respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.json { render json: @events }
 end
```

Answer (score 0):

So [options_from_collection_for_select](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_from_collection_for_select) just takes the collection you pass into it and doesn't specifically use anything from the controller unless you specify it to. Your code `options_from_collection_for_select(Category.all, :id, :title)` queries from the database via the `Category.all`.

It looks like you're storing the info from the API in `@events` (though that looks like an event list not a categories list). If you had a variable you generated from the API that you assigned to `@categories` then you could use it in your view like this:

`options_from_collection_for_select(@categories, :id, :title)`